# Slick code generator with static dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, slick

I'm trying to use Slick 2.1 with MS SQL Server in my Play 2.3 application. I'm stuck with trying to make Slick's code generator to work in `Build.scala`. This is because MS SQL Server JDBC driver is not on maven and I'm just manually putting the driver jar file in the `/lib` folder. At the moment I'm getting this error:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

This is how the part where code generator is looks like:

```
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
    val outputDir = (dir / "slick").getPath
    val url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb"
    val jdbcDriver = "com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver"
    val slickDriver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver"
    val pkg = "db"
    toError(r.run("scala.slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, user, pswd), s.log))
    val fname = outputDir + "/db/Tables.scala"
    Seq(file(fname))
}
```

How do I make MS SQL Server JDBC driver play along with Slick code generator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SBT in Play 2.3 doesn't seem to automatically add contents of `lib` folder to classpath, so I've stumbled on a solution after running `idea` command for my Intellij IDEA which among other things adds jars from lib to classpath.

Also, after lots of digging around the final solution to this particular problem was to use open source `jtds` driver for slick code generator and ms jdbc driver for the rest of the application. This is what generator code ended up looking like:

```
lazy val slickCodeGenTask = (sourceManaged, dependencyClasspath in Compile, runner in Compile, streams) map { (dir, cp, r, s) =>
    val outputDir = "app"
    val url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb"
    val jdbcDriver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
    val slickDriver = "com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver"
    val pkg = "db"
    toError(r.run("scala.slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator", cp.files, Array(slickDriver, jdbcDriver, url, outputDir, pkg, user, pswd), s.log))
    val fname = "Tables.scala"
    Seq(file(fname))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a tangential note, for sbt 0.13.x, it is recommended to change `scala.slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator` -> `slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator`